# SQL Server 2017 Foreign Key Relationship Window - Does it have typo?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-server-2017

I noticed **Foreign Key Relationship** window in SQL Server 2017 there is a collapsible part called **INSERT And UPDATE Specification** and when you open this part there are two items under it which are:**Delete Rule** and **Update Rule**.

Delete Rule and Update Rule makes sense. But I think the INSERT And UPDATE Specification should change to INSERT and DELETE Specification.

Is this a typo or I am making a mistake?
[image: Foreign Key Relationship Window in SQL Server 2017]

Comment: Google to see if anyone else has noticed this and if not, post a question in the SQL server fourm.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/home?forum=sqltools

Comment: I did not search a lot but i didn't find anything. So if I don't get something here, I might post to SQL Server forum.